Started a service in stopped state using Ansible
I'm trying to create an ansible playbook to start a service if it's only in stopped state. Created the below playbook.
tasks:
   - name: Check the Service Status
     ansible.builtin.command: systemctl status mariadb.service
     register: service_status
     notify: Mariadb restart
     changed_when: service_status.rc != 0
     ignore_errors: true


  handlers:
    - name: Mariadb restart
      ansible.builtin.service:
         name: httpd
         state: restarted

When I run this playbook it's failing even I mentioned ignore_errors statement in task.
TASK [Check the Service Status] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.1.102]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["systemctl", "status", "mariadb.service"], "delta": "0:00:00.016680", "end": "2024-11-21 00:20:53.396153", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 3, "start": "2024-11-21 00:20:53.379473", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "○ mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5 database server\n     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)\n     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-11-20 23:30:01 EST; 50min ago\n   Duration: 3min 52.893s\n       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)\n             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/\n    Process: 12935 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n    Process: 12957 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n    Process: 12992 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n    Process: 13004 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n   Main PID: 12992 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n     Status: \"MariaDB server is down\"\n        CPU: 526ms\n\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5 database server...\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5 database server.\nNov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.5 database server...\nNov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Deactivated successfully.\nNov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.5 database server.", "stdout_lines": ["○ mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5 database server", "     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)", "     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-11-20 23:30:01 EST; 50min ago", "   Duration: 3min 52.893s", "       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)", "             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/", "    Process: 12935 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "    Process: 12957 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "    Process: 12992 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "    Process: 13004 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "   Main PID: 12992 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "     Status: \"MariaDB server is down\"", "        CPU: 526ms", "", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5 database server...", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5 database server.", "Nov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.5 database server...", "Nov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Deactivated successfully.", "Nov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.5 database server."]}
...ignoring

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.1.102              : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1

Can someone help me with this?
I want to start the service only if it's in stopped status.



fatal: [192.168.1.102]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["systemctl", "status", "mariadb.service"], "delta": "0:00:00.016680", "end": "2024-11-21 00:20:53.396153", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 3, "start": "2024-11-21 00:20:53.379473", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "○ mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5 database server\n     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)\n     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-11-20 23:30:01 EST; 50min ago\n   Duration: 3min 52.893s\n       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)\n             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/\n    Process: 12935 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n    Process: 12957 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n    Process: 12992 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n    Process: 13004 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n   Main PID: 12992 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)\n     Status: "MariaDB server is down"\n        CPU: 526ms\n\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5 database server...\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.\nNov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5 database server.\nNov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.5 database server...\nNov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Deactivated successfully.\nNov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.5 database server.", "stdout_lines": ["○ mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5 database server", "     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)", "     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2024-11-20 23:30:01 EST; 50min ago", "   Duration: 3min 52.893s", "       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)", "             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/", "    Process: 12935 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-socket (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "    Process: 12957 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "    Process: 12992 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "    Process: 13004 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "   Main PID: 12992 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)", "     Status: "MariaDB server is down"", "        CPU: 526ms", "", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.5 database server...", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 mariadb-prepare-db-dir[12957]: If this is not the case, make sure the /var/lib/mysql is empty before running mariadb-prepare-db-dir.", "Nov 20 23:26:08 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5 database server.", "Nov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopping MariaDB 10.5 database server...", "Nov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Deactivated successfully.", "Nov 20 23:30:01 RHEL-Node-2 systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.5 database server."]}
...ignoring



The playbook is not failing. The error (rc:3) is ignored because you wanted to ignore_errors: true.

If the task result is fatal the handler is not notified. Instead of
ignore_errors: true

set
failed_when: service_status.rc > 3

This solves the problem of notifying a handler by failed command (rc=3 in your case). However, it doesn't necessarily solve the problem "to start the service only if it's in stopped status."


Example of a complete playbook to test the handler
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - command: 'false'
      register: status
      notify: Mariadb restart
      changed_when: status.rc != 0
      failed_when: status.rc > 3

  handlers:

    - name: Mariadb restart
      debug:
        msg: Restart Mariadb



Do not use ansible.builtin.command for this purpose. This is expected to fail as your command is returning rc != 0 so the module perceive this as a failure.
There is other modules that can help you with this such as ansible.builtin.systemd
See example here
- name: Get Service Status
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: mariadb
  register: result

- debug:
    var: result.status.ActiveState

- name: Mariadb start if in inactive state
  ansible.builtin.service:
    name: mariadb
    state: started
  when: result.status.ActiveState == 'inactive'


Also one note on your usage of changed_when and handlers. These should be used when your task is making actual changes on the system. Here you're just looking for the state of something, so you're not making changes. As you can see above you just need to useregister to save the result of your task and use an appropriate when statement to apply the intended logic.
See links for more info:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_service_module.html
Ansible: How to get service status by Ansible?


Thank you for the explanation, yeah this is working...
I found another method as well using service facts.
tasks:


name: Collect Service Facts
ansible.builtin.service_facts:


name: Start the service
ansible.builtin.service:
name: mariadb
state: started
when: ansible_facts.services['mariadb.service'].state == 'stopped'


